# WKWebKit does not refresh webpage

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I am using Xcode 8.3.3 and Swift 3 to develop an app for the iMac using Cocoa. My goal is to use `VCgoToWebPage` and display a webpage to the user. My program calls this function many times, but the only webpage I see is the last one called. How do I implement a window refresh inside this function and wait for the webpage to be fully rendered?

```
func VCgoToWebPage(theWebPage : String) {
    let url = URL(string: theWebPage)!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request)

    /*The modal box allows the web pages to be seen. Without it, after a series of calls to VCgoToWebPage only the last page called is displayed.  The modal box code is just for debugging and will be removed.  */

    let alert = NSAlert()
    alert.messageText="calling EDGAR page"
    alert.informativeText=theWebPage
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
    alert.runModal()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigation delegate to make sure navigation to a page is complete before trying to load another. Have your class conform to `WKNavigationDelegate` and set `webView.navigationDelegate` to that class instance.

```
var allRequests = [URLRequest]()
func VCgoToWebPage(theWebPage : String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: theWebPage) else {
       return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    if webView.isLoading{
       allRequests.append(request)
    } else {
       webView.load(request)
    }
}
func webView(WKWebView, didFinish: WKNavigation!){
    if let nextRequest = allRequests.first{
       webView.load(nextRequest)
       allRequests.removeFirst()
    }
}
```